# Django Create View URL conflicts with Single View URL

Tags: python, django

My *url.py* file is as below.

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.loans, name='loans'),
path('loans/<str:pk>/', views.loan, name='loan'),
path('loans/create/', views.create_loan, name='create-loan'),
]
```

Whenever I try to access the *loans/create* route, Django throws the below exception.

```
ValidationError at /loans/create/
['“create” is not a valid UUID.']
```

It looks like Django is passing *'create'* into *'loans/<str:pk>/'*

How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URL patterns are iterated over in order and the first match is returned, the `pk` parameter in your `loan` url will always match the string "create". You need to swap them around so that the create url is tested first

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.loans, name='loans'),
    path('loans/create/', views.create_loan, name='create-loan'),
    path('loans/<str:pk>/', views.loan, name='loan'),
]
```