# Django is not loading the URL I defined

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am working on a project that generates dynamic urls, For ex. if I type **127.0.0.1:8000/newpage** it generates a new model with slug **newpage**

Earlier the project was working fine but suddenly it started to show some bugs.
I am calling a URL using ajax like this ***(5th line)***:

```
$(document).on('click', '#save', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{% url "text:update" %}',
                data: {
                    newText: $('#text-content').val(),
                    slug: "{{ obj.slug }}",
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}",
                    action: 'post'
                },
                success: function (json) {
                    if (json['status'] === 'OK') {
                        document.getElementById('msg-box').innerText = 'TEXT SAVED';
                        window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", beforeUnloadListener, { capture: true });

                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {

                }
            });
        });
```

It should load the view which I defined in the update url patterns but because of some reason it is still loading my slug view and generating a new url with slug update, I mean it shouldn't do that if I am telling it to load a specific view in URL pattern then why it is still loading slug view below is my urls.py:

```
#Only patterns
path('', home, name='home'),
path('<slug:slug>/', textview, name='textview'),
path('update/', update, name='update'),
```

**views.py**

```
def textview(request, slug):
    obj, created= Text.objects.get_or_create(slug=slug, defaults={'text':'', 'password':'123'})
    return render(request, 'text/textpage.html', {'obj' : obj, 'created' : created})

def update(request):
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        slug = request.POST.get('slug')
        text = request.POST.get('newText')
        obj = Text.objects.get(slug=slug)
        obj.text = text
        obj.save()
        response = JsonResponse({'status':'OK','text':text})
        return response
```

Comment: Please add code of your views

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Create View URL conflicts with Single View URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70230648/django-create-view-url-conflicts-with-single-view-url). `"update"` is a valid slug so is being caught by the `textview` path, put the `update` path before it so it's matched first

Comment: @IainShelvington I did that and it is working perfectly fine but the problem is when I generate dynamic urls with update as slug it will load the update view instead of create view Let me add views file to give you an idea

Comment: @AliIrani I have added Views file

Comment: If the slug can equal 'update' you should change the url-shema to not have conflicting urls. You could use something like `text/<slug:slug>/` for example...

Comment: @PawelKam Thanks for the suggestion but this thing came to my mind but I didn't wanna do it that way, the slug has to get generated just after the site name. that is what the project requires

Answer (score 0):

Where are you using this AJAX code? If it is in a JavaScript file (.js), Jinja won't work there, so you have to write the absolute URL or you have to define a variable for the Jinja in the HTML and then use that variable in the JS file.

And try to add a slash after the URL if your `APPEND_SLASH` not True in `settings.py`.

Comment: AJAX is in the <script> tag in the HTML